# Cursor query ever return 1 in mCount

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query in SQLITE Android :

```
Cursor cursor = Application.getInstance().getContentResolver().query(DAOProvider.URI_EXECSQL, new String[]{getSingleQuery(idPatient)}, null, null, null);`
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
      {
        String id = cursor.getString(0); // The result of all the values are null
      }
    }
```

This is the result of the query (All values are null, the table is empty):

[image]

The problem is that ever return count = 1 , but I dont have any record in my DB, my table is empty , and the cursor thinks that exist 1 record, but the problem is that the Cursor have all the values in NULL.

Is necesary any other configuration to check if the query have results? 
Add Dump Cursor:

```
Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@24371d87
0 {
   id_person_patient=null
   id_blood_type=null
   cenRegister=null
   name=null
   paternalSurname=null
   maternalSurname=null
   sex=null
   curp=null
   rfc=null
   registerDate=null
   birthday=null
   email=null
   id_nationality=null
   id_state=null
   IFNULL(nfcp.id_statusnfc, 0)=0
   COUNT(pr.id)=0
   id_person_tutor=null
   id_relationship=null
   name=null
   paternalSurname=null
   maternalSurname=null
   sex=null
   curp=null
   rfc=null
   registerDate=null
   birthday=null
   email=null
   id_nationality=null
   id_state=null
   IFNULL(vc.apply, 0)=0
   id_person_user_alta=null
   nfccount=0
}
```

Comment: if not sure about your `Cursor` content use `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` method

Comment: `"""This is the result of the query (All values are null, the table is empty):"""`, no, the table is not empty, you have one row (with all the fields either = 0 or NULL)

Comment: The problem is   IFNULL(nfcp.id_statusnfc, 0)=0 , this make that the query return a 0 value in the row  of the results.

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: The query verify if a value is NULL , if the condition is true, the query put 0 in the row value, making that the query return 1 row in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have one row with null values for `id_person_patient` and `id_blood_type`. If the table was empty, the `moveToFirst()` would return false and obviously the count wouldn't be `> 0`.

If you still don't want to believe that, consider this: 
`SqliteCursor` extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` extends `AbstractCursor`.

`AbstractCursor.moveToFirst()` calls `moveToPosition(0)`. Here's `moveToPosition()`,

```
public final boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
    // Make sure position isn't past the end of the cursor
    final int count = getCount();
    if (position >= count) {
        mPos = count;
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

You passed 0 for position, so it must return false if count was 0. In summary, moveToPosition() cannot return true if getCount() returns 0.

Comment: but, if the result was founded, the result is the same, the count would be 1, my query only returns one result.

Comment: How do we know the count isn't one? Read for yourself: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst() "This method will return false if the cursor is empty."

Comment: The table is empty, the cursor must return false, but, the cursor return count = 1 with null values in the columns. When I have DATA in the table and id_person exist, the query return count = 1 because the item exist. I dont have idea wich is the problem.

Comment: "The table is empty"- I have no idea if you are making a statement or asking a question. It doesn't look empty. Your screen shot shows it with one row full of null values. "I dont have idea wich is the problem"- there's no problem. You have a table with one row where the values are null.

Comment: Is not a question, the table, is empty, the table donsn't have any value.

Comment: If you upload your .db file somewhere I'll take a look.

Comment: Clearly it dosnt have any record, When I apply select count(*) from MyTable the result is 0 . If I export the table,  the scheme dosnt have any row.

Comment: Okay, then Android is broken. Better call Google and let them know. This is serious!

Comment: After check, the result of one of the values was the count of a value that dosnt exist, there was the problem.